# Resume paused activity with intent filter?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

In my app I'm using twitter auth, and my activity at some moment of time opens a browser using `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "path to twitter"));` to allow user to confirm access. Same activity has intent filter

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="twconnect" android:host="success" />
        </intent-filter>
```

so when user confirms access, he is being redirected back to this activity. But instead of just resuming previously paused activity, it creates a new one, calls `onCreate` and, I believe, creates new task with empty back stack. Is there any way to resume paused activity in it's task?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Android controls what activity will remain in Background or will be killed (if I'm not wrong). If he needs more memory, it will kill the Activity and recreate when necessary. Try to pass and get your data in **savedInstanceState**. You should make a logic to control the state (if twitter were opened yet and continue the process)

Comment: No good, it didn't pass my savedIstanceState to new activity.